# Events in Html component of react-three/drei not working

Tags: three.js, react-three-fiber, react-three-drei

I want to create a button in my Canvas:

```
<Canvas>
  <Html>
    <button onClick={() => console.log("Test")}>Test</button>
  </Html>
</Canvas>
```

But when I click the button, nothing is shown in the console.